# jQuery image slider opacity

Tags: html, slider

I am working on an image slider. 
But I have some questions.
First I'd like to do that when I hover over the "next" or "prev" buttons so the right or the left side only the specific button would apper not both. 
Second, I'd like to make the opacity nearly the same as shown in this slider. (link below)

URL : uchicago.edu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show only one button when you hover one side you can do this:

html:

```
<div id="leftButtonArea">
  <div id="leftButton">left</div>
</div>
```

style:

```
#leftButtonArea{
   position:absolute;
   top:0px;
   left:0px;
}

#leftButton{
  display:none;
}
```

script:

```
$("#leftButtonArea").hover(function(){$("#leftButton").css({"display":"block"})});
```